# Query to mongodb using where clause and multiple $or

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I'm building a rails(3.2) app where i've used text search following the procedure described [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax). I'm using `mongodb`. According to the link i've provided in **controller** i've wrote:

```
@products = Product.search(params[:search])
```

Also in the **model**:

```
def self.search(search)
    if search
      where(organization_name: /#{search}/ ) 
    else
      scoped
    end
  end
```

My problem is : I've three fields `organization_name`, `title` and `description` where i have to search the text. In the above code i only search the text in only the `organization_name` field. I need to query like :

1. search text is whether in `organization_name field` **or** `description` field **or** `title` field
2. The search described by **Railcast** is case-sensitive. How can i make it case-insensitive search?

Comment: the link you provided is for `ActiveRecord`, do you use a similar ORM for mongoDB? (hint http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/index.html )

Answer (score 1):

In the mongo console your query would look like this (`search` has to be your search string):

```
db.products.find(
    {
        $or: [
            { organization: { $regex: search, $options: 'i' } },
            { descrption: { $regex: search, $options: 'i' } },
            { title: { $regex: search, $options: 'i' } }
        ]
    }
)
```